# VBS script error 800A03F4

Tags: windows, vbscript

I am getting this error when I am trying to make a custom screensaver.
It says: (script location)
Line: 20 
Char: 4 
Error: Expected "If" and when I chane it it also says expected end or something else.
The idea is to launch a screensaver I have made in a .bat script and it will detect when to launch it. Also, could I also have some help detecting that the mouse isn't moved for the time specified?
Anyway, here is what I have done so far:

```
set service = GetObject ("winmgmts:")
Dim StartTime, EndTime, Elapsed
StartTime = Timer
Elapsed = Timer - StartTime
If Timer > 100000 Then
for each Process in Service.InstancesOf ("Win32_Process")
If Process.Name = "cmd.exe" then
sleep 0
else
createObject("WScript.Shell").Run "screensaver.bat"
StartTime = 0
EndTime = 0
Elapsed = 0
Timer = 0
end
```

thanks in advance ~ Dan

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the source code of your batch file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated the script so it launches the screensaver properly, but still doesn't detect idle time and the timer doesn't really work. I changed the script.

Answer (score 0):

The default `If` statement is

```
If True Then
  WScript.Echo "True"
End If
```

If you delete the `If` in `End If`, you get the Expected 'If' error.

In your code you 'open' two Ifs and one For. Close them properly and indent your code.